# How can I get the current position of the cursor (curses)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, curses

I'm trying to get the current location of the cursor and I can't seem to be able to do that.
Apparently, the `stdscr.getxy()` is supposed to return the current position, however it does not seem to return the correct location.

[image: Returned values by getmaxyx and getyx]

As you can see, `getyx()` returns a very similar value to `getmaxyx()`.
The cursor is on line 2 at character 24, so the Y coordinate (27) makes sense, however the X coordinate (99) doesn't. Shouldn't it be something like 76 (100-24)?

Answer (score 1):

curses uses a *virtual* screen and a *physical* screen.  The *virtual* screen contains the information that your program sets, while the *physical* screen is what actually appears on the terminal after optimizing the cursor movement.

You're seeing the latter (the physical screen), which will only correspond to the virtual screen after doing a *refresh*.  Normally (when your program reads a character from the keyboard), those are equivalent (because `getch` does a refresh).

Answer (score -1):

I use a module called [`pyautogui`](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to trace the cursor:

```
import pyautogui

var = pyautogui.position()
```